# Arduino Interrupt won't ignore falling edge

Tags: arduino, interrupt, avr, isr, debouncing

I'm having some trouble completely debouncing a button attached to to an interrupt. The goal is to have the statement in the `void loop()` run exactly once when the button is pressed/released.

What usually ends up happening is one of two things

1. The ISR flag is set once when the button is pressed. Releasing the button does nothing, as intended.
2. The ISR flag is set once when the button is pressed, and once more when the button is released.

Here is the exact code I have:

```
#define interruptPin 2

#define DBOUNCE 100

volatile byte state = LOW; //ISR flag, triggers code in main loop
volatile unsigned long difference;

void setup() {
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), ISR_0, CHANGE);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if(state){ //If we have a valid interrupt
    Serial.println(difference); //Print the time since the last ISR call
    state = LOW; //Reset the flag
  }
}

void ISR_0() {
  static unsigned long last_interrupt = 0;
  if(millis()-last_interrupt > DBOUNCE && digitalRead(interruptPin)){
    difference=millis()-last_interrupt;
    state = HIGH; 
  }
  last_interrupt = millis(); //note the last time the ISR was called
}
```

This seems to be a popular way to debounce an interrupt, but for whatever reason it isn't working for me.

I was hoping on the first falling edge of the button release that `digitalRead(interruptPin)` would read `low`, so the `state` flag would not be set.

Since the ISR updates the `last_interrupt` time, the successive bounces after the first falling edge still seem to be successfully ignored. This leads me to believe the debouncing is not the issue, but the `digitalRead(interruptPin)` is.

The debouncing seems to take care of all but one state. When the button is released, the code still occasionally sets the `state` flag to `HIGH`.

Here's some sample output:

`3643` (after waiting ~3.6 seconds from boot, I press the button, releasing it ~1 second later)

In the same scenario as above, the output occasionally looks like this:

```
3643
1018
```

This shows me pressing the button, but also releasing the button.

I'm using an UNO R3 and a momentary tactile push button with a 1k pull-down resistor.

I'm not sure what's going wrong at this point. I hope this is simple enough that anyone can easily test this on their arduino if they feel so inclined.

Comment: You're attaching the handler to a pin change interrupt. That means, if the pin is not changed interrupt will not be called again. So, `state = HIGH;` will never be performed until pin state change (button is released or pressed again). It is not a way to do the debounce.

Comment: Yes. Every time the button is pressed, or bounces, the ISR is called. The `state` flag is only supposed to be set `HIGH` if the logic level change is determined to not be a bounce, and if the pin state is `HIGH`. Passing these conditions should indicate the first press of the button. @AterLux What part of the `if` statement in the ISR is not a way to debounce?

Comment: The idea of debounce is to check the button is still pressed for a certain amount of time after the pressing was dected for the first time. Your interrupt will work only if time from when it was called last time is greater than DBOUNCE. I.e. it just measure time between button was released and pressed again and do nothing with debouncing

Comment: That is certainly one technique to debouncing, but not an ideal one for my application. In my system, there is no noise, so we can assume the first interrupt is in fact a valid button press, and everything after that is either the button release, or a bounce. I chose this technique because it works quickly for time-sensitive applications, since it immediately identifies the first state change (and ideally nothing after). I also know that there will be no consecutive valid button presses that happen in a time span shorter than the debounce period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debouncing buttons/switches in interrupts is a hassle.

I faced a (sort of) similar situation with limit switches.
The moment a limit switch is hit, something has to occur - so interrupt.

However the interrupt would fire when the limit switch was released as well which was a problem. I had my interrupt set to fire on a FALLING edge.

Anyhow, I wound up debouncing outside of the interrupt, using flags.
The code explains it but:
Switch is hit, ISR runs (does what it needs to) and sets an ISR flag.
The ISR flag stops the ISR from actually doing anything until it's cleared.
In the main loop, call a debounce function if the ISR flag is set.
the debounce function will wait until a pin/switch is stable at the required state (HIGH/LOW) for a predefined time, then clear ISR flag, allowing the ISR to do something again.

```
#define interruptPin 2
#define DEBOUNCE_TIME 100L

volatile bool ISR_ACTIVATED = false;
volatile bool display_int_time = false;
bool debounce_started = false;
unsigned long Isr_debounce_pin_timer;
volatile unsigned long difference;

 void setup() {

  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), ISR_0, CHANGE);
  Serial.begin(112500);

}


void loop() {

  if (display_int_time) {  
    Serial.println(difference); //Print the time since the last ISR call
    // Right, done with interrupt stuff. clear the interrupt flag
    display_int_time = false;
  }
  // Call debounce ISR routine in main loop
  if (ISR_ACTIVATED)
    ISR_ACTIVATED = !debounce(interruptPin, HIGH, Isr_debounce_pin_timer);

}

bool debounce(int debounce_pin, bool state, unsigned long &state_latch_start) {
  // debounce_pin - what pin are we debouncing?
  // state - should the stable state be HIGH or LOW
  // state_latch_start - when we 'latched' on to a (possibly) stable state

  static bool current_state;

  // Read the required pin
  current_state = digitalRead(debounce_pin);

  // Is the pin at the required state, and we have not yet 'latched' it?
  if ((!debounce_started) && (current_state == state)) {
    // 'latch' this state (ie take note of when the pin went to the required level)
    state_latch_start = millis();
    debounce_started = true;
  }

  // Have we 'latched', but the pin has bounced
  if (debounce_started && (current_state != state))
    // unlatch
    debounce_started = false;

  // Have we latched, the pin is at the required level and enough time has passed (ie pin is stable)
  if (debounce_started && (current_state == state) && (((unsigned long)(millis() - state_latch_start)) >= DEBOUNCE_TIME)) {
    // cool. unlatch
    debounce_started = false;
    // report back that all is goood.
    return(true);
  }

  // Blast. Either the pin is at the wrong level, or is still bouncing. Tell the boss to try again later!
  return(false);
}

void ISR_0() {


  static unsigned long last_interrupt = 0;
  if((millis()-last_interrupt > DEBOUNCE_TIME) && digitalRead(interruptPin) && !ISR_ACTIVATED){
    difference=millis()-last_interrupt;
    //state = HIGH; 
    ISR_ACTIVATED = true;
    display_int_time = true;
  }
  last_interrupt = millis(); //note the last time the ISR was called
}
```

*** Just a note, edited my code to incorporate the debounce time in your original ISR to ensure that the interrupt is valid. I had not read the comment regarding your noisy environment

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your code worked immediately. I ended up modifying it a small bit by just removing a few redundant things and unused variables.

Answer (score 1):

You use the internal pullup resistor of the Uno, but also a pulldown resistor on the button itself. That's not correct, you can only use one of of them.
Inside the if, you want the input to be high, so use the pulldown resistor and change INPUT_PULLUP into INPUT.

(to make things clear: the resistor is connected between input pin and ground, the button between input pin and +5V)

[edit]

I think when the ISR is called, the status of interruptPin might be changed again.
Due to the slowness of digitalRead, compared to the (possible) spike.

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but the example below is working.
(I've enabled the LED for testing purposes).
One thing: keep the button pressed at least the debounce time (100msec), otherwise it won't work.
Not ideal, but that's the price you have to pay if you want instantly response on a switch.

```
#define interruptPin 2
#define DBOUNCE 100

volatile byte state = LOW; //ISR flag, triggers code in main loop
volatile unsigned long difference;
bool hasPrinted = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT);
  pinMode (13, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), ISR_0, CHANGE);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, state);
  if (!hasPrinted) {
    Serial.println(difference);
    hasPrinted = true;
  }
}

void ISR_0() {
  static unsigned long last_interrupt = 0;
  if(millis()-last_interrupt > DBOUNCE){
    state = !state;
    hasPrinted = false;
    difference = millis()-last_interrupt;
  }
  last_interrupt = millis(); //note the last time the ISR was called
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That's merely an error in my post. I've mostly been using the pin mode `INPUT` and a button with a pull down resistor, but as a last-ditch effort, I tried the UNO's own pull up resistors with pin mode `INPUT_PULLUP` and a button connected to ground. That is why you see the pinmode in the code above.

Unfortunately, both setups seem to have the same problem. Occasionally, the button release still sets the flag in the ISR.

Answer (score 1):

### You can always do debouncing in the hardware

I've encountered bounce several times with buttons and encoders, and doing debouncing in the software can get messy and lead to unreadable code or logic errors.

The easiest thing you can do is add a 0.1 uF capacitor, as illustrated:

[image: simple debouncing circuit]

The Arduino has hysteresis inputs, and if you use 10K as your pullup then this works for bounce that is under 1ms. This is my favorite approach.

If you wanna get more serious, a **wonderful** pdf exists on the internet with lots of examples and explanations: [A Guide to Debouncing](https://pubweb.eng.utah.edu/~cs5780/debouncing.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the main issue, as was said in the comments, is because you have no actual debounce.

So, after the button is released, it continues to bounce, causing logic level on the input pin to change. If at the moment, when the pin state is latched for the digitalRead(), the state was read as high, then the whole condition will be met and `state = HIGH;` will be performed.

I'm not an artist, but I did my best to draw this timing diagram:

[image: Time diagram of the button bounce]

So, to avoid this, you can utilize any simple approach to debounce. Most simple one is to read again the pin state after a little timeout, greater than the maximal expected bounce time.
For example, if you're waiting for the button to be pressed and got high logical level (or low if the button is connected to GND), just wait about 5ms and read the level again. Process the button press only if the level still high (low).

And as was said in the other answers, hardware debounce also will help. You can use a higher resistor (actually you need not use external resistor: connect the button to GND and enable the internal pull-up, which is about 35kOhm). And add a capacitor about 1nF, parallel to the button.

Comment: I guess I never realized there could still be bouncing while the ISR is running. I think I just assumed `digitalRead()` would be at the edge of the state change triggering the ISR.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution, thanks to @darrob

```
#define interruptPin 2
#define DEBOUNCE_TIME 50L

//ISR Flags
volatile bool ISR_DEACTIVATED = false;
volatile bool display_int_time = false;

bool debounce_started = false;
unsigned long Isr_debounce_pin_timer;

int x = 0;


void setup() {
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), ISR_0, CHANGE);
  Serial.begin(112500);
}


void loop() {

  //This runs every time we press the button
  if (display_int_time) {  
    Serial.print("X "); //Print the time since the last ISR call
    x++;
    (x%10==0)?Serial.println(x):Serial.println();

    display_int_time = false; //Done with interrupt stuff. Clear the interrupt flag
  }

  //Debounce for the ISR routine in main loop
  if (ISR_DEACTIVATED)
    //Wait until the pin settles LOW to reactivate the ISR
    ISR_DEACTIVATED = !debounce(interruptPin, LOW, Isr_debounce_pin_timer);

}


//Returns TRUE if pin is stable at desired state, FALSE if bouncing or other state
bool debounce(const int debounce_pin, const bool state, unsigned long &state_latch_start) {
  // debounce_pin - what pin are we debouncing?
  // state - should the stable state be HIGH or LOW
  // state_latch_start - when we 'latched' on to a (possibly) stable state

  //If you are calling this routine to debounce multiple pins in the same loop,
  // this needs to be defined outside of the function, and passed in as a separate
  // parameter for each debounce item (like unsigned long &state_latch_start)
  static bool current_state;

  // Read the required pin
  current_state = digitalRead(debounce_pin);

  // Is the pin at the required state, and we have not yet 'latched' it?
  if ((!debounce_started) && (current_state == state)) {
    // 'latch' this state (ie take note of when the pin went to the required level)
    state_latch_start = millis();
    debounce_started = true;
  }

  // Have we 'latched', but the pin has bounced
  if (debounce_started && (current_state != state))
    // unlatch
    debounce_started = false;

  // Have we latched, the pin is at the required level and enough time has passed (ie pin is stable)
  if (debounce_started && (current_state == state) && (((unsigned long)(millis() - state_latch_start)) >= DEBOUNCE_TIME)) {
    // cool. unlatch
    debounce_started = false;
    // report back that all is goood.
    return(true);
  }

  //Either the pin is at the wrong level, or is still bouncing. Try again later!
  return(false);
}


void ISR_0() {
  if(!ISR_DEACTIVATED){
    ISR_DEACTIVATED = true;
    display_int_time = true;
  }
}
```